# Getting unexpected basic authentication prompt for a single page that is not secured

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a webforms application that I am securing using forms authentication. My issue is that for some url's I am getting a basic authentication modal dialog prompt (unexpectedly) even when the user is logged in. Other pages are fine and don't exhibit this behaviour.

This is only occurring on the staging server and **not** in my development environment. Here are my relevant configurations:

- Staging server is running IIS 8
- web.config

> ```
> <system.web>
>   <authentication mode="Forms">
>     <forms loginUrl="Account/Login" timeout="120" defaultUrl="/" />
>   </authentication>
>   <pages validateRequest="false" clientIDMode="AutoID">
>   </pages>
>   <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
>       <providers>
>         <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="GliderWorks" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
>       </providers>
>  </membership>
>  <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
>       <providers>
>         <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="GliderWorks" />
>       </providers>
>  </profile>
>  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
>       <providers>
>            <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection".....
>       </providers>
>  </roleManager>
>  <siteMap defaultProvider="SitemapNone">
>           <providers>
>             <clear />
>             <add name="SitemapAdministrator" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="WebHorizontalMenuAdministrator.sitemap" />
>             <add name="SitemapNone" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="WebHorizontalMenuNone.sitemap" />
>             <add name="SitemapSuperAdministrator" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="WebHorizontalMenuSuperAdministrator.sitemap" />
>           </providers>
>  </siteMap>
> </system.web>
> <!-- Site Security -->   <!-- Allow anonymous access to Public Area
>  -->   
> <location path="Public">
>   <system.web>
>     <authorization>
>       <allow users="*" />
>     </authorization>
>   </system.web>   
> </location>   <!-- Entire site is secured -->   <location path=".">
>   <system.web>
>     <authorization>
>       <deny users="?" />
>     </authorization>
>   </system.web>   
> </location>   <!-- Allow anonymous access to api -->   
> <location path="api">
>   <system.web>
>     <authorization>
>       <allow users="*" />
>     </authorization>
>   </system.web>   
> </location>   <!-- /Site Security -->
> ```

and a relevant sitemap SitemapSuperAdministrator.xml configuration file:

Comment: I was also facing a similar problem a few days ago. it got resolved when i disabled caching.

Comment: how did you disable caching?

Comment: I was using mvc, so just removed the output cache attribute from the controller.

Comment: Hmmmm this is WebForms so not as simple as that unfortunately. Thanks I will give it a go and see what happens.